# dill.detect.at Cannot reference object at '0x1023d2600'

Tags: python, garbage-collection, dill

More digging into dill. Specifically the detect.at method which is a call to:

```
def _locate_object(address, module=None):
    """get object located at the given memory address (inverse of id(obj))"""
    special = [None, True, False] #XXX: more...?
    for obj in special:
        if address == id(obj): return obj
    if module:
        if PY3:
            objects = iter(module.__dict__.values())
        else:
            objects = module.__dict__.itervalues()
    else: objects = iter(gc.get_objects())
    for obj in objects:
        if address == id(obj): return obj
    # all bad below... nothing found so throw ReferenceError or TypeError
    from weakref import ReferenceError
    try: address = hex(address)
    except TypeError:
        raise TypeError("'%s' is not a valid memory address" % str(address))
    raise ReferenceError("Cannot reference object at '%s'" % address)
```

Why am I not able to "get" the string object which appears to be at the address: `4332529152`?

```
>>> class Parent():
...     name="Big Papa"
...     def get_hitched(partner):
...             return name + "+" + partner + "TLFE"
... 
>>> johnny = Parent()
    >>> johnny = Parent()
>>> johnny.get_hitched("Mary")
'Big Papa + Mary TLFE'
>>> billy = johnny.get_hitched
>>> billy("Junebug")
'Big Papa + Junebug TLFE'
>>> dill.detect.reference(billy)
4299844816
>>> dill.detect.reference(johnny.get_hitched)
4299844816
>>> dill.detect.reference(johnny)
4299844816
>>> dill.detect.reference(johnny.name)
4332529152
>>> dill.detect.reference(Parent)
4332953328
>>> dill.detect.at(4332529152)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/mikekilmer/Envs/GLITCH/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dill/dill.py", line 738, in _locate_object
    raise ReferenceError("Cannot reference object at '%s'" % address)
ReferenceError: Cannot reference object at '0x1023d2600'
>>> 0x1023d2600
4332529152
>>> id(johnny.name)
4332529152
>>> type(johnny.name)
<type 'str'>
```

Comment: exception weakref.ReferenceError

from weakref.ReferenceError: Exception raised when a proxy object is used but the underlying object has been collected. This is the same as the standard ReferenceError exception. Reading up on weak references...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Detect.at() takes a reference number and, *if it is a reference number that would be handle by the garbage collect module*, returns the object that it is associated with. Otherwise returns ReferenceError: and the hex value of the reference number.

For example, instance attributes are not managed by GC because they will be destroyed when the objects they are linked to are destroyed.

As roippi says in comment:

All they're doing here is searching through gc.get_objects() and comparing objects by id - which is exactly how you're supposed to use id. The actual reason you can't dereference johnny.name is that class/instance attributes are not directly tracked by the garbage collector - there's no need to, since you can just destroy them when you destroy the objects they're linked to.

And the hex number is simply the result of calling the `hex()` method on the reference number input to `dill.detect.at()`.

Answer (score 0):

Fundamental problem here: The id() of an object is not its address. It might happen to be, in CPython, but it's not something you can make use of. I don't know what _locate_object is supposed to be used for, but that looks like fundamentally bad code. Can you explain what you're really trying to accomplish here?

Python doesn't work with memory addresses, it works with object references. Every object has an identity, which is an integer. Some Pythons simply assign sequential integers when the id() is requested, nothing more. All you can be sure of is that no two distinct objects that exist simultaneously have the same id, and that an object's id never changes throughout its lifetime.

Comment: 1) the code is from `dill`, a (popular) third party library and 2) the function searches for the value in `gc.get_objects()`, which is a list of the same unique identifiers returned by `id`.

Comment: actually all i'm trying to do here is understand what the detect.at function in dill is supposed to do. how it's supposed to work, and what a decent use-case example might be.

Comment: I can't help there. All I can say is, id() is not returning an address, so it's fundamentally impossible to dereference it. All you can do is try to find a matching object. And if you retain the id of an object without somewhere retaining a reference to it, you risk that object ceasing to exist and another one getting the same id, because ids can be reused.

Comment: But don't the reference objects have memory addresses? when i `id(johnny.name)`, isn't `4332529152` the memory address of the reference object? (I run type() on it and get `<type 'int'>`.)

Comment: `dill.at` is used inside `dill` for pickling weakrefs, which only have an address. `dill.at` is a sort of last ditch attempt to find the real object before giving up and raising an exception.

Comment: @MikeiLL Forget "addresses", that's a red herring.  All they're doing here is searching through `gc.get_objects()` and comparing objects by `id` - which is exactly how you're supposed to use `id`.  The actual reason you can't dereference `johnny.name` is that class/instance attributes are not directly tracked by the garbage collector - there's no need to, since you can just destroy them when you destroy the objects they're linked to.

Comment: @roippi so in this case `4332529152` is in fact the id by which `johnny.name` is referenced, but when `johnny`, with reference id `4299844816` is destroyed, `johnny.name` at `4332529152` will also be removed and it's memory freed, so therefor `gc.get_objects()` does not return it and instead returns the `ReferenceError`, mentioning the memory `address` (`0x1023d2600`). Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: @MikeiLL yep, that's about it.